# bulk_create how to call function on each object

Tags: python, django, django-models

In reference to the following `bulk_create` query:

```
objs = [
        Message(
            recipient_number=e.mobile,
            content=content,
            sender=e.contact_owner,
            billee=user,
            sender_name=sender,
            gateway=gateway,
        )
        for e in query

    ]
    # Send messages to DB
    Message.objects.bulk_create(objs)
```

**My issue:**

I have to use bulk_create (for performance reasons). However I need to call `instance.send(gateway)` on every object that's created.

Using bulk create I don't seem to beable to do it because PK is not necessarily available for `post_save` signal **meaning this won't work**....

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Message)
def my_post_save_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.send(instance.gateway)

post_save.connect(my_post_save_handler, sender=Message)
```

So I have tried a few other things like this....

```
objs = [
    Message(
       etc...
    ).send(gateway)
    for e in query

]
```

**again this won't work.**

This issue is driving me a little mad, it's very simple, so what options do I have with example?

**I don't wont to use create, have to stay with bulk_create as I'm inserting millions of objects!**

Thank you. :)

Comment: If creating a `list` of millions of objects is not a problem, then you could add a flag field that would indicate whether the message has been sent, and after `bulk_create` fetch all objects with this flag unset (or a subset of fields) and perform sending.

Comment: Just curiosity: how do millions of objects fit into the query string? I mean, have you tweaked your db or did some optimizations django-side? I imagine it would be difficult to send few megabytes query to the server.

Comment: Couldn't you just loop over `objs` and send each one after the bulk create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to save the result of send, but send returns None. Instead you should call send in each object in turn, then send all the objects to bulk_create:

```
for obj in objs:
    obj.send(gateway)
Message.objects.bulk_create(objs)
```

Comment: No, send pushed the message out. Message HAS to be saved before I can call send(gateway) i.e. It has to be done after saving the message.